# PHP Static function creating and returning an object OR creating an object, and calling a function on it

Tags: php

Would this method

```
    foreach($data as &$d)
       $obj[]=ClassName::createObject($data);
```

or

```
    foreach($data as &$d){
       $obj[] = new ClassName;
       $obj[end($obj)]->loadData($data);
     }
```

-

```
     class ClassName{
        public static function createObject($data){
              $obj = new ClassName;
              //do stuff with $data
              return $obj;
        }

        public function loadData($data){
              //do stuff with $data;

        }

     }
```

The ::createObject method makes for code which is a lot less painful to read while the second method doesn't have to return huge objects.
I'm not sure how variables are handled in a language like PHP so is there a big difference in performance?
Which method would be best to use?

Comment: I think you're operating under a misconception.  Objects in PHP aren't like arrays in how they're passed around by default.  All that is returned when you pass one into a function/method or return one is a reference to the object (think of it as a pointer).  So you're not going to be "passing huge objects around", just fairly small references. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: I think it should be createObject($d), should it? If you do not modify the $data, then you shall not use the & as this costs performance (yes, this is contra-intuitive). Regarding your question: PHP only returns a reference, so alternative 1 is probably faster because there is one method call less - but actually the difference shall be marginal.

Comment: This: `$obj[end($obj)]->loadData($data);` won't work - `end()` returns the **element** that is last in the array, not the **index**. You would need something similar to `$obj[count($obj) - 1]->loadData($data);`.

Comment: Yep, Should hvae been createObject($d);
Okay, Thanks guys.
Lots of information here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First looks ok. You don't need to pass `$d` by reference in this case. And probably you want `ClassName::createObject($d)`. Still I'd refactor it to:

```
foreach($data as $d) {
   $obj[]=new ClassName($d);
}
```

This is just ugly, not for performance reasons:

```
foreach($data as &$d){
   $obj[] = new ClassName;
   $obj[end($obj)]->loadData($data);
 }
```

Instead you could do this:

```
foreach($data as &$d){
   $object = new ClassName;
   $object->loadData($d);
   $obj[] = $object;
 }
```

If the data is essential for the object - set it from the construct. If the data is optional, then the `loadData` method makes sense. But if you want to move the construct logic to a static method - this is pointless. No performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

the static method does not give any advantages. The factory method as static is functionally identical to the new keyword (which is also static). You suggest that it saves a single line of code but if you always need to call ->loadData() on the object after it's constructed then you should pass data into the constructor:

```
$obj = new ClassName($data);
```

Using a static method call in this instance does not solve any problems and simply adds complexity/bloat.